# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: how to set correct Java parameters

Tags: java, parameters, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s)

Hi,

can anyone please provide setting the Java parameters from the command prompt...

I am getting the Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`: Java heap space in my program

Thanks

Comment: what is the parameter that you passing in?

Comment: Are you certain this is not caused by a _memory leak_?  If it is, adding memory will only increase the time between crashes.

Answer (score 2):

```
java -Xmx128m ...
```

This sets the max heap size to 128MB. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

```
eclipse -vmargs -Xmx128m
```

This tells eclipse to use 128MB as heap size for launched applications. See http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can set -Xmx:512M argument to increase maximum possible memory for usage.

Comment: There must not be a `:` in `-Xmx:512M`. It should be `-Xmx512M` (or `-Xmx512m`) if you want to set the max. amount of memory to 512 MB.

Answer (score 0):

When launching from a command prompt try increasing the memory allowance, eg:

```
eclipse -vmargs -Xms128m -Xmx512m
```

Where 128m is the min and 512m is the max heap size.

Answer (score 0):

Tune -XX:MaxPermSize also.

This parameter will also laed to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError